# How to keep drop down navigation open after hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is a jsbin [link](http://jsbin.com/noveyorica/edit?html,css,js,output) to my code. As you can see, the drop down closes as soon as I hover away from the trigger thus making the navigation useless.

Any simple solutions would be very welcome. Thanks in advance.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
  <p>Menu</p>
  <ul>
    <li>list</li>
    <li>list</li>
    <li>list</li>
    <li>list</li>
  </ul>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

SASS

```
*
  margin: 0

header
  padding: 20px
  background-color: tomato
  p
    display: inline
    padding: 5px 10px 
    background-color: blue
    color: white
    &:hover
      cursor: pointer
  ul
    padding: 10px
    background-color: blue
    list-style: none
    color: white
    width: 60px
    display: none
```

JS

```
$(function(){
  $("p").hover(function(){
    $("ul").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: `mouseenter` / `mouseleave`

Comment: wrap in div and use hover for div http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/wfw1f9to/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  $("p").hover(function(){
    $("ul").show();    
  });
  $("ul").hover(function(){}, function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: yes but then it stays there, how do i make it go away once i hover outside of the box?

Comment: @EliTamosauskas I've updated the answer. Do you mean that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JS for  this. Use :hover in your css:

```
header:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wfw1f9to/3/